# How to extend textmate perl bundle to include snippets from perldoc

Tags: perl, textmate

I am starting to learn perl and I want to have as many code snippets ready to go so I can get moving as quickly as possible. Perldoc looks like its full of snippets so I wondered if there was a way of extending the perl bundle in textmate so that I could have ready access to these. I may be being naive.....

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using TextMate 2, have a look at this answer:

https://superuser.com/a/380592

It tells how to create new snippets.

Comment: That's not really what Im looking for. I don't want to add snippets one by one. I would like to have a library of importable snippets so I can use textmate as a snippet library

Comment: Alright, well then perhaps define better what you want. How do you want to access the snippets, do you want to be able to browse them or just access them by name? Do you want them as native TextMate snippets you just don't want to add them all by hand? What is a `library of importable snippets`? Imported to where? Another program or a code file open in TextMate. Expound please.

Comment: My apolgies if this was not clear. Really what I want is to be able to to quickly store snippets from wherever into textmate. One possibility I suppose is to store Gists from Github in textmate. I know that the textmate gists bundle can be configured to send snippets to gists (https://github.com/hiltmon/Gist.tmbundle) but I can't find a way of searching through gists using textmate and then storing the snippets I like in textmate. Maybe I'm asking too much